# How to close C# process?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wrote a simple program using Visual Studio(C#). When I close my program(click at Х) the form is closed, but the process remains. I had to close it from Task Manager.

What is the command to close process? 
My code:

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {                     
     e.Cancel = true;          
 }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you should try and find the root cause of the problem. Why is your program not closing when you close the form? Do you have an infinite loop somewhere that has references to `Application.DoEvents()`?

Comment: @StevenLiekens the form is not closing, since he is cancelling the closing of the process ?

Comment: @ilansch the author probably wrote that part of the code in an attempt to fix the problem, not knowing that it would only set him back further.

Comment: @StevenLiekens the author is setting properties of parameters with out understanding the purpose of these properties. This is a bad practice for him :) and one of the worst thing a new programmer can do

Comment: Exactly. Which is why I suspect that an infinite loop in combination with `DoEvents()` is what's causing this. Classic beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The `e.Cancel=true` will prevent your form from closing, so remove it.

if it still doesn't work, try this : 
use the `Application.Exit()` method on the `FormClosed` event instead of `FormClosing`:

To do this, go into your form designer window : press maj + F7 or right click on your form in your solution explorer and click on `Form designer` (something like that)

Right Click on your Form, Select `Properties`, display the Events, then double-click on the Form Closed event and the designer will automaticaly register the event and generate your code.

You should have something like this without the `Application.Exit()` method generated :

```
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{                     
    Application.Exit();          
}
```

Comment: where is i have to paste this method?

Comment: And btw, the 'e.cancel=true' prevents your form from closing

Comment: I used method Application.Exit() on the FormClosed, but no changes. Form closed, process remains.

Comment: Show us the code of the registration to event, and the updated function Form1_FormClosed please

Comment: @user3360977: i think you need to show us more code, if your form1 is you main and only form and that you don't use threads or running methods, the application should stop.
ilansch : i'll explain how to register the event via the form designer.

Answer (score 0):

`e.Cancel = true;` means stop the form from closing. That's the main issue with your code.

You should use this parameter if you have a confirmation something like "Are you sure you want to close?" if the user selects "No" you set `e.Cancel` to `true`.

Just remove that code (or set Cancel to false) and your form will close, and if that's the last one of your application, it will end.

So the final solution for your problem is a simple

```
 private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
 {                     
 }
```